# How can I return true or false after for loop

Tags: java

I've written a code and the code sorts array values. My code has to return boolean but it did not go well as I imagined or I did.

The console says; "This method must return a result of type boolean".

Here is my code

```
    double array[] ={3.2,9.4,7.1,1,2,4.1,8.88};
    //                       i     j1
    isItSort(array);
    wrtOut(array);

}

public static boolean isItSort(double[] numbers)
{

    int j=0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        for(j =i+1; j<numbers.length; j++)
        {
            for(int j1 = j; j1<numbers.length; j1++)
            {
                boolean check = numbers[i]<numbers[j1];
                if(check)
                {

                    double temp = numbers[j1];
                    numbers[j1]= numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = temp;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

public static void wrtOut(double[] numbers){

    for(int i=0; i<=numbers.length-1;i++ )
    {

        System.out.println(numbers[i]);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Guess what happens if you pass an empty `double[]` to the method.

Comment: If i'll add an empty return It gonna work without problem(I know that). So i do not understand something why do i need to use return statement if it will work perfectly with void.

Comment: I do not understand why people gives downvote asking. Were you not also a beginner once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because you don't have a returned value for all the possible cases in your method, indeed for example if `check` is never `true` you don't return any value with your current code, you should return a default value at the end of your method as next:

```
public static boolean isItSort(double[] numbers) {
...
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what does it do return there, when I write false or true? For me it seems not efficent.Is it better to use in void this case? How could be more efficent for you with void or with boolean?

Comment: Returning false here makes sense because if we reach it, it means that check has always been false such that result is false

Answer (score 1):

isItSort() - only for loop is having return statement. Compiler is not sure that method will return successfully or not so its giving error. What will happen if

boolean check = numbers[i]

does not give true. The method will not be able to return any value if for loop ends without executing below block

if(check)
                {

```
                double temp = numbers[j1];
                numbers[j1]= numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = temp;
                return true;
            }
```

So, ideally you should return false, if no condition satisfies. So, write a return false at the end of the method. the program will run.

Answer (score 1):

Your method 'isItSort' have a boolean return and you declare to return true if your if statement was true, but not always the condition will be satisfied, for this reason the compiler say to you add boolean return in the end of method for example:

```
    public static boolean isItSort(double[] numbers)
    {

        int j=0;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            for(j =i+1; j<numbers.length; j++)
            {
                for(int j1 = j; j1<numbers.length; j1++)
                {
                    boolean check = numbers[i]<numbers[j1];
                    if(check)
                    {

                        double temp = numbers[j1];
                        numbers[j1]= numbers[i];
                        numbers[i] = temp;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       return true; <!-- you need to put appropriate return here -->
  }
```

Comment: Could void be better alternative instead of boolean.(thanks for perfect explanation) @Júlio Dias